# Setting header on ListView prevents scrolling when the delegate has MouseArea

Tags: qt, qml

I have a ListView and its delegate has a MouseArea. If the ListView doesn't have a header, everything works well. However, if I set a header, I can only click on the delegates but can't scroll.

What's is more interesting is that when I set the header's width to half the width of the window, I can scroll normally on the right side of the screen (where there's no header), but can't scroll on the left side under the header.

EDIT: Experimented with this a bit and found another thing. The delegate's height is 80 and if I set the header's height to, say, 30, then I can't swipe when the mouse lands on the top 30 pixels *of a delegate* as if the header is attached to each item in the list?

---

[edited code] This the full code that recreates the problem for me (can't scroll on the left side but can on the right). I'm using qt 2.15

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15


Window {
    id: root

    width: 640
    height: 600
    visible: true




    ListView {
        id: list
        anchors.fill: parent

        model: 20
        delegate: Rectangle {
            signal clicked();

            implicitHeight: 70
            width: root.width

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                z: 2
                onClicked: console.log("clicked");
            }

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "text"
            }
        }

        // Works fine when I comment this out
        headerPositioning: ListView.OverlayHeader
        header: Rectangle {
            z: 2
            implicitHeight: 100
            implicitWidth: root.width / 2
            color: "blue"
        }
    }
}
```

Example (the header is blue):

[image]

Comment: Definitely `width: root.width` is `width: list.width` and `implicitWidth: root.width` is `implicitWidth: list.width`. Also I have not been able to reproduce the error. Code works fine for me. You should maybe post the entire code, or you should use the code you have pasted here since it works fine in most cases

Comment: @surge10 Hmm, I just copied the code from the post to a completely new project and it still has that problem. Maybe this depends on the qt version? I have Qt 2.15. Just in case, the problem is not about the width of the header. In the gif, I intentionally set the width to ``root.width / 2`` to show that I still can scroll on the left side but not on the right.

Comment: Just edited the post to include a complete code that recreates the problem (for me at least)

Comment: Weird. Works fine for me with QtQuick 2.11, .Window 2.1, .Controls 2.1. I'll try newer versions later.

Comment: Thanks everyone. So I tried this in an online compiler and it indeed works. I guess I'll try to reinstall qt

Comment: Try setting MouseArea::scrollGestureEnabled to false.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess, nope, didn't work... I figured to just put a rectangle separate from the list view as the header for now and until I reinstall Qt. Anyway, the problem is too specific to my qt for whatever reason and can't be recreated so I probably should close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-101727 was written up about this; probably the same as QTBUG-89409.  And we fixed it already in 5.15.7.  It's also OK in Qt 6.

Note that if you press on the header itself and try to flick, you won't be able to, in any version; that's intentional: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-74046

Answer (score 0):

The problem turns out to be too specific and can't be recreated so I guess I should close the question.

(SO asks me to wait for 18 hours...)